# Firebase in iOS project causing drop in code coverage numbers

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, jenkins

Jenkins code coverage of my iOS project is let's say x%. If I comment the following line in app delegate,

```
[FIRApp configure];
```

the coverage increases by 5%.Any idea why? 
Also, How can I stop this line from being executed when the test are being run?

Comment: 0
down vote
I have the same issue - any progress with it?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase adds a bunch of files to the app target causing a change in code coverage.

You can see this when you open up the coverage section and expand your target. I bet what is happening is when you add the line of code it knows you need to import Firebase, and is adding in those files, decreasing your code coverage.